# Handlebars if statement inside another helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

Is it possible to do the following inside of handlebars:

```
{{#each (if someArray ? someArray : otherArray)}}
  //do something with element from array
{{/each}}
```

or I have to do it like this:

```
{{#if someArray}}
  {{#each someArray)}}
    //do something with element from array
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  {{#each otherArray}}
    //do something with element from array
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

For example, I've created a helper 'count' witch I could use inside of the other helper but also standalone:

```
{{count someArray}} // standalone: will print length of array
{{#if (count someArray)}} //inside if
  //if someArray.length > 0
{{else}}
  //if somArray.length = 0
{{/if}}
```

This is just an example to show how could be possible to use nested helpers. I would like to know if it's possible to use 'if' condition inside of helper.